# sonar, jacoco, and maven are not cooperating for me

Tags: maven-3, sonarqube, jacoco

- Maven 3.0.4
- sonar-maven-plugin 2.2
- jacoco-maven-plugin 0.6.4.201312101107

When I run `mvn sonar:sonar`,  the `prepare-agent` goal of the jacoco-maven-plugin fails to run, so the agent arguments aren't there for surefire when needed.

When I explicitly run `mvn prepare-package sonar:sonar`, I get an infinite recursion in jacoco initialization.

Apparently I'm missing something, but what?

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <!--
                  Prepares the property pointing to the JaCoCo runtime agent which
                  is passed as VM argument when Maven the Surefire plugin is executed.
              -->
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                          <propertyName>jaCoCoSurefireArgLine</propertyName>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>default-report</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure plenty things to make jacoco works. Check that configuration:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.6.2.201302030002</version>
  <executions>
    <!-- prepare agent for measuring unit tests -->
    <execution>
      <id>prepare-unit-tests</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Also you can refer to my blog post dealing with multimodule projects with unit and integration tests: http://www.kubrynski.com/2013/03/measuring-overall-code-coverage-in.html